# Optimize Or Pipes (|) in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am running a multi-pipe Regex on text blocks that are about 3,000 characters long. I have 6 different and the matches are always in the same order relative to one another and complicating it is I always want to prioritize the last one firsst

```
Pattern1|Pattern2|Pattern3|Pattern4|Pattern5|Pattern6
```

Right now I am testing on a block of text that finds Pattern1. Standalone it takes 41 steps, in the pipes it takes over 30,000. I get that it might take more specific information for this specific problem, but was wondering if there were some generic steps to take to make and/or pipes more efficient. Is there an "order" that helps? Clearly this is not testing the first pattern and then quitting since it would still be 41 steps so wondering if I need to adhere to some basic and/or construction I am unaware of.

Comment: I guess a fair first question is: why are you using a regex for this?

Comment: Yes, the basic is that the pattern is tested at each position in the string (from left to right) with each branch (and not the whole string branch by branch).

Comment: I don't fully understand how your individual regexes are related, but could you split them into independent searches? If so, then you could use the multiprocessing module to set up worker processes that each search for just one of the terms. Perhaps some post-processing could organize the results into a format you need. I'm unaware of any way to simplify the given regex any more.

Comment: combining similar starting patterns into groups may help. say the patterns are `aab|abc|bb`, it may help to change it to `a(?:ab|bc)|bb`. This does have the drawback of having much higher maintenance since you cannot simply pipe patterns together/modify them independently.

Comment: @RadLexus I am using Regex for all my initial text extraction which my coder uses in his python script. I am avoiding to the degree necessary post-processing so trying to do as much work on the regex end as possible. The pipes work fine and well but was hoping to reduce overhead as much as possible.

Comment: To reduce backtracking, make sure each branch cannot match at one and the same position inside the string. So, `Pattern1|Pattern2|Pattern3|Pattern4|Pattern5|Pattern6` > `Pattern[1-6]`.

Comment: How did you calculate the 41 steps and 30,000 steps ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak Using Regex101

Answer (score 0):

The main point about optimizing alternation groups is **the alternative branches should not match at the same location**.

Consider a string that has many similar substrings to those in your pattern above:

```
Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern  Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern Pattern2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iU6nN2/1). The `Pattern1` is tried first, and it matches `Pattern` but since there is no digit after it, the alternative is discarded and the next branch is tried. `Pattern2` also goes up to the digit, but there is no digit. And so on.

If you make your regex start with a common prefix and then use a group for the different endings - like [`Pattern(?:1|2|3|4|5|6)`](https://regex101.com/r/iU6nN2/2) - a lot of redundant backtracking is spared.